# Some tutorials with Eclipse/WindowBuilder Pro

Tags: eclipse-rcp, windowbuilder

I am looking for  tutorials about how to write a rcp program with window builder pro, any resources links, OK?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970614/searching-for-windowbuilder-documentation-api

Answer (score 7):

You can find the official user guide [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Findex.html).

Comment: many thanks, but i want a personal tutorial on how to use window builder in a plugin /rcp project...

Comment: It would be the same. Once you grasp how the window builder works you can use it in any kind of project. The logic specific to the plugin/rcp part have nothing to do with window builder itself.

Answer (score 4):

Google has four tutorials [here](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/tutorials/loginmanager.html).